# Long-Poll with Spring MVC 3.2 and Database SQL (JPA-hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, long-polling

I was looking for a week for a example using Long-polling way with spring MVC but without succes, I want to get notifications from a table, and send the appropriate notifcation to the right user which his ID is in the notification row. Once this is available I find the deferredresult class but I did not get it, I would like to know how do spring know if there is a new row in notification table with a long-poll call and how can I achieve this, I didn't find any example yet for long-polling with spring mvc and a Database. Can someone help?

Comment: How about web socket with postgres? http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/04/postgresql-nofify-websocket-spring-mvc.html

Comment: Hi , thx but i have to do this at work (notifications) with spring mvc 3.2 and a sql database :D